# How to fix "no view found for id"?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

The project is working fine, however the problem appeared when I add "switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageC());" this is the logcat [image: logcat]

Here is the code for *BaseFlashCardsFragment*

```
package com.flashcards;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BaseFlashCardsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BaseFlashCardsFragment extends Fragment implements     View.OnClickListener {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private int position;
private String mParam2;

public BaseFlashCardsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param position Parameter 1.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BaseFlashCardsFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BaseFlashCardsFragment newInstance(int position) {
    BaseFlashCardsFragment fragment = new BaseFlashCardsFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = null;
    int layoutId;
    switch (position) {
        case 0: layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment1; break;
        case 1:layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment2; break;
        case 2:layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment3; break;
        default: layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment4;break;
    }
    rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonterm).setOnClickListener(this);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttondefinition).setOnClickListener(this);
    switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageA());
    switchPage1(new limits_fragmentpageB());
    switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageC());
    switchPage3(new limits_fragmentpageD());
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int viewId = view.getId();

    if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm) {
        switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageA());
    }
    else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition) {
        switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageAA());
    }

    if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm) {
        switchPage1(new limits_fragmentpageB());
    }
    else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition) {
        switchPage1(new limits_fragmentpageBB());
    }

    if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm) {
        switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageC());
    }
    else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition) {
        switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageCC());
    }

    if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm) {
        switchPage3(new limits_fragmentpageD());
    }
    else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition) {
        switchPage3(new limits_fragmentpageDD());
    }
}


private void switchPage (Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer1, fragment)
            .commit();
}
private void switchPage1 (Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer2, fragment)
            .commit();
}
public void switchPage2 (Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer3, fragment)
            .commit();
}
private void switchPage3 (Fragment fragment){
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer4, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

}

Here is the code for *limits_fragmentpageC*

```
package com.flashcards;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class limits_fragmentpageC extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.limits_fragment_flashcards_c,   container, false);
}
}
```

Here is the XML Layout, this includes the *activity_main_fragmentcontainer3*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">
        <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Title 3"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonterm"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Term"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttondefinition"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Definition"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_fragmentcontainer3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/framelayout_border">
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="(Swipe to Navigate) \n    (3 of 10 Cards)"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<include layout="@layout/include_toolbarbottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try using setContentView. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579668/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment-placeholderfragment

Comment: Its not working, if I remove switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageC());
it will work, but I want to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

in place of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

I'm pretty sure this is causing your problem because I had the same log output recently when I used `getFragmentManager()`.

While working with support library version of `Fragment`, you should always use `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Well, the getFragmentManager() is working fine within these two:

  switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageA());
    switchPage1(new limits_fragmentpageB());

And when I add  "switchPage2(new limits_fragmentpageC());" the error appears. I will try your suggestion sir.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() is not working, it says "cannot resolve method 'getSupportFragmentManager()'".

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() is a method of Activity (or probably AppCompatActivity to be specific). If you want to call getSupportFragmentManager() from inside a Fragment, you should use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(). Also make sure that your host Activity extends AppCompatActivity. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but I think that the way you're handling ViewPager is wrong.

Comment: But I want a switch or slide feature sir. :( I will email you now thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

first dont use this line more than once in your layout

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

second you use support fragment so you need to use getSupportFragmentManager() from the activity but because you want to use fragment inside a fragment you need to use getchildfragmentmanager()